# How to make console visible on all Visual Studio Code tabs?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In Visual Studio Code, there are tabs on the left: Explorer, Search, Source Control etc. You can move the terminal panel around these places. For example, you can place it in the search tab in the bottom part of the tab panel:

[image]

I'd like to see the Terminal on whichever tab I am currently on. If it is Explorer, Search, Source Control etc. I'd like to see the console at the bottom. How to do it?